# perforce diff between 2 files in different directories .

Tags: perforce

Perforce : My system is such that at compile time few files are created in a temp directory . 
Requirement is that ; If the created file is different from the file present in workspace then we copy file from temp directory onto workspace after doing a check out of the file present on the workspace.

How can I do a diff between 2 files in my workspace and get an output if the files are same or different .

Comment: Can't you just run the 'diff' command? What operating system are you using on your workstation? If it is, say, Linux or Mac OS X, there should be a 'diff' command present in your shell. If it is Windows, you can install something like Cygwin or Ubuntu on Windows, and then you'll have a diff command there, too.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this:

1. Copy the file(s) into the workspace.
2. Run "p4 reconcile".

If the files are identical, this will be a no-op.  If the files are different, you will get the end result you want (modified files in workspace, opened for edit).

Comment: It might be convenient to set your workspace to "allwrite" for this approach